# A bounded linear operator that is close to a unitary operator should be invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $T,U$ are bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$, with $U$ unitary.  If $\|T-U\| < 1$, then show that $T$ is invertible.

Injectivity is easy: Suppose $z \in \ker T$, then $\| (T-U)z \| < \|z\|$ for $z \neq 0$ which implies that $z = 0$. So $T$ has to be injective.

What about surjectivity?

Comment: Are $f, g$ supposed to be $T, U$?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have fixed it.

Comment: Have you seen the special case of this involving $I$? It involves a geometric series. This case is typically used to show that invertible operators are open in the set of all bounded linear operators.

Comment: $U$ mean "you" is you-nitary, right?

Comment: That is, $g = U$, right?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to show this uses a result from Banach algebra theory (if I can think of a more elementary way to show this, I'll edit my answer to include it).

> Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra with unit $1_A$.  If $a\in A$ and $\|a-1_A\|<1$, then $a$ is invertible.

If you haven't seen this, a proof should be found in almost any book on functional analysis, and definitely in one which has a chapter on bounded operators on Banach spaces (or a chapter on Banach algebras).

Returning to the question at hand:  since $\|T-U\|<1$, we have 
$$\|U^*T-1\|=\|U(U^*T-1)\|=\|T-U\|<1.$$
Thus $U^*T$ is invertible, and therefore $T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Neumann series.

Show that $$\|1-TU^{-1}\|<1$$ and

$$
TU^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-TU^{-1})^k =\text{Id}
$$

just how you'd show that

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^k=(1-q)^{-1}
$$